# Error al introducir una imagen en React (img) ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin

Tags: html, reactjs

Tengo un problema, estoy programando algo en React JS, al intentar introducir una imagen de **InstaGram**

> https://instagram.fctg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/174409207_817868725471277_4375095502464602042_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fctg2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=RKm8JbtG6Z0AX9ANdZk&edm=AOQ1c0wBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfDeoh-gelvk3AAQG_d6JKwy-FXPA_UCw8qVExXlafBwXQ&oe=65782919&_nc_sid=8b3546

```
<img src={data.picture_profile} alt={`USUARIO: ${data.username}`} />
```

Pero obtengo el error en consola de 'ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin'  y no carga la imagen.

Psdt: Ya probé usar crossorigin='anonymous' y el otro atributo con 'noreferrer'

Ayuda, GRACIAS.

Conseguir cargar imágenes de instagram en pagina web